# Puppeteer Memory Increase Problems

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, puppeteer

I'm running Puppeteer script both on my Amazon Linux EC2 Instance and my Macbook Air (OSX).
The script has to stay in tact at one page and repeatedly perform form-filling tasks over and over again.

I'm encountering issues where i'm running it as a `pm2` daemon process, I can see that the memory consumption of that process is increasing every minute or two until it's clogging the server's memory.

In order to overcome it, I used `--max-memory-restart` flag of `pm2` and it prevents the server from crashing, but the node process restarts every 30 minutes in average.

Here is the example that represents the code i'm running:

```js
// Require the puppeteer library
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function scrape() {
    // Create the browser
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        args: [
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
            '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
            '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
            '--no-first-run',
            '--no-zygote',
            '--single-process',
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--ignore-certificate-errors'
        ]
    });

    // Wrap scraping/testing code in try
    try {
        await initialFlow(browser, null); // Page instance is null for the first time
        // Catch and log errors
    } catch (error) {
        // Your chance to handle errors
        console.error(error);
    } finally {
        // Always close the browser
        await browser.close();
    }
}

const initialFlow = async (browser, page) => { // Save resources by reusing the browser and page instances
    try {

        if (!page) {
            const pages = await browser.pages();
            page = pages[0];
        }

        await page.setRequestInterception(true);

        page.on('request', (req) => {
            if (req.resourceType() == 'font' || req.resourceType() == 'image') { // Save resources by denying images and fonts from being rendered
                req.abort();
            } else {
                req.continue();
            }
        });

        await page.goto('about:blank'); // Go to blank page
        await page.goto('https://www.google.com'); // For the example

        await page.waitForSelector('#Form', { visible: true });
        return await initialFlow(browser, page); // Perform the actions again on the same browser and page instances

    } catch (err) {
        return await initialFlow(browser, page);
    };
}

// Run our function
scrape().catch(console.error);
```

When running this example, the memory displayed in the `pm2 ls` command start from around 30mb and continuously increases as the time goes by.

Any suggestions to prevent this memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

Kudos on putting `browser.close()` in a `finally` block even though you're entering an infinite loop. For many other visitors to the thread, a typical memory leak problem is failure to close browsers on all paths through the code.

However, it's rather bizarre to use recursion instead of a loop. Luckily, since it's async, the stack won't blow, but the code is hard to understand since some conditional initialization occurs in the function. Misunderstanding the control flow is probably leading to your leak.

One problem is that you keep adding your request handler to the page over and over on every `initialFlow` call:

```js
page.on('request', (req) => {});
```

These handlers stack on top of each other, chewing up memory. Here's a minimal example you can run to observe the problem using a memory profiler:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.1.0
const {setTimeout} = require("timers/promises");

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  for (;;) {
    page.on("request", () => {});
    await setTimeout(10);
  }
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Just add this handler one time up front and you should be OK, assuming there's nothing else in the code that was lost in translation to the snippet you shared here.

Quick rewrite, untested:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function scrape() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    args: [
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
      "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
      "--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas",
      "--no-first-run",
      "--no-zygote",
      "--single-process",
      "--disable-gpu",
      "--ignore-certificate-errors",
    ],
  });

  try {
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);
    page.on("request", (req) => {
      if (
        req.resourceType() == "font" ||
        req.resourceType() == "image"
      ) {
        return req.abort();
      }

      req.continue();
    });

    for (;;) {
      try {
        await page.goto("about:blank"); // Go to blank page
        await page.goto("https://www.google.com"); // For the example
        await page.waitForSelector("#Form", {visible: true});
      }
      catch (err) {} // FIXME risky -- consider detecting if we hit
                     // this branch repeatedly so we can log it
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
  finally {
    await browser.close();
  }
}

scrape().catch(console.error);
```